# Slice/subset in R using vector/matrix/list as indices

Tags: r, subset, slice

We can get element at 2nd row, 4th column as

```
iris[2,4]
```

How to do the same if I have a vector/matrix of the slicing elements. ie can i get any of the following to give the same output as iris[2,4] ? (Or anything similar, without creating any temporary variables)

```
a = c(2,4)
b = matrix(c(2,4), nrow=1)
c = list(2,4)
iris[a]
iris[b]
iris[c]
```

Comment: `iris[b]` works ?

Comment: @RonakShah It does, but the output is a 'character' vector. It coerces numeric/factors to character. Don't want that.

Comment: What about taking the individual elements of the vector? Like your vector `a` example: `iris[a[1],a[2]]`

Comment: @drmariod actually i wanted to slice a `matrix` by directly using the output of `arrayInd(which.min(mtrx), dim(mtrx)` , and wanted a general approach to slicing df, matrix etc. In short, the `a` variable was just an example, I wanted to directly use the `c(2,4)`. Accepted answer works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is coerced to character because you're using a `matrix` method for subsetting, and one of the columns is of class character.

We can circumvent this in two ways. Either we remove the character column beforehand,

```
v <- c(2, 4)
m <- matrix(c(2, 4), nrow=1)
l <- list(2, 4)

iris[,-5][t(v)]
# [1] 0.2
iris[,-5][m]
# [1] 0.2
iris[,-5][do.call(cbind, l)]
# [1] 0.2
```

or we use a `list` method for subsetting. (`iris` is a `data.frame`, so both are applicable)

```
iris[[rev(v)]]
# [1] 0.2
iris[[rev(c(m))]]
# [1] 0.2
iris[[rev(unlist(l))]]
# [1] 0.2
```

---

I know it's been years, but I just wanted to reiterate that `rev()` is necessary when using the output from `match(, arr.ind=TRUE)`

```
mat <- matrix(c(1:9, 1:7), 4)
(dtf <- as.data.frame(mat))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  5  9  4
# 2  2  6  1  5
# 3  3  7  2  6
# 4  4  8  3  7

(id <- which(mat == 8, arr.ind=TRUE))
#      row col
# [1,]   4   2

mat[id]
# [1] 8

dtf[[rev(id)]] # Traverse as list; first column, then row
# [1] 8

dtf[id] # Indexing as matrix; first row, then column
# [1] 8

dtf[[id]] # Does not work
# Error in as.matrix(x)[[i]] : 
#   attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex

dtf[[c(id)]] # Wrong index
# [1] 5


### Multiple matches
(id <- which(mat == 2, arr.ind=TRUE))
#      row col
# [1,]   2   1
# [2,]   3   3

mat[id]
# [1] 2 2

dtf[id]
# [1] 2 2

dtf[[rev(id)]] # Does not work any more
# Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
#   recursive indexing failed at level 2


### Why traversing a data.frame as list can be useful
(dtf$V1 <- as.character(dtf$V1))
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"

(id <- which(dtf == 1, arr.ind=TRUE)) # Will match both characters and numerics
#      row col
# [1,]   1   1
# [2,]   2   3

dtf[id] # Returns both as character
# [1] "1" "1"

l <- lapply(data.frame(t(id)), 
  function(x) {
      dtf[[rev(x)]]
  }
)
sapply(l, class) # Retains classes
#          X1          X2 
# "character"   "integer"
```

Comment: The list subset method indeed takes in vector directly for slicing. Thanks, that solves my problem. But `rev` function isnt required. rev sorts the vector, hence doesnt give the correct result. directly feeding in the vector does the job.

Comment: Is it because `data.frame` can be seen as a list of columns, such that it requires `rev()` within `[[ ]]`? Just want to learn the fact behind....

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding: Yup. Passing a vector to `[[]]` traverses a nested list. The columns in a `data.frame` counts as the top level. `\``